# How to detect lines in this pic using opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

[image]

I don't know why opencv can't find out the lines using HoughLines,
the result is follow,

[image]

But if I use another picture from the internet,
[image]

voila. Any ideas?

Comment: your input image is very blurry. sort that out first!

Comment: 1. You should post your code 2. Go through the tutorial (the code is in C++, but there are python corresponding functions) http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html

Comment: you don't know why OpenCV does not find the lines because you blindly use things you don't understand. you put diesel in a petrol engine and wonder why it won't run... do yourself a favour and read a book on image processing or leave image processing to experts.
I recommend "Digital Image Processing: An Algorithmic Introduction using Java" by Burger & Burge.

Comment: yeah, I'm really sorry about that. Just in such a ruch :(. I'll try to understand the underlying principles.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Hough detect the lines extremities. A gradient is probably computed during the process.

A solution would be to:

1. Binarize the image
2. Compute the black region skeleton
3. Skeleton pruning
4. Apply the Hough Transform.

Doing that, each line will be reduced to 1 pixel width.

[EDIT] Here is an example:

1. [The test image binarized](http://www.thibault.biz/StackOverflow/Hough.png)
2. [The skeleton](http://www.thibault.biz/StackOverflow/Hough_Skeleton.png) (simple thinning).
3. [The result](http://www.thibault.biz/StackOverflow/Hough_Lines.png) (I skipped the pruning).

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing an actual example of this!

Comment: Houghlines is very sensitive to different parameters. Try LineSegmentDetector.

Comment: I've just added an example